# SQL Server 2005 query specific results grouping and order by

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2005.

Please consider the following query:

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(4)
SELECT @SearchTerm = 'X'

SELECT ProductCode -- NVARCHAR type
FROM Product
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
```

**How may I specify the correct grouping / order by clause to my query to order the results by the following specific criteria?**

1. Firstly, order by ProductCode ascending where ProductCode STARTS with @SearchTerm
2. Then order the remaining results by ProductCode ascending.

So for example the results may look like:

```
ProductCode
-----------
XAA
XMA
XZA
AXA
AXZ
BAX
BMX
BXZ
etc.
```

Any answers as ever are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for the answers however I have come up with my preferred solution myself based off noting the syntax other answers have used `LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'`, i.e. dropping the first `'%'` gave me the clue which reminded me of an old Excel trick:

```
SELECT ProductCode
FROM Product
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
ORDER BY CASE WHEN LEFT(ProductCode, LEN(@SearchTerm)) = @SearchTerm THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ASC, ProductCode ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

The following should do what you want. First we order by the ProductCode ASC IF it starts  with the search term (note: your where clause evaluates to if the ProductCode contains anywhere in it the @SearchTerm, not just starts with). Then we order by ProductCode.
If the search ProductCode does not start with the @SearchTerm then we just order by ProductCode (because all the first order by values will be null).

```
DECLARE @SearchTerm NVARCHAR(4)
SELECT @SearchTerm = 'X'

SELECT ProductCode 
FROM Product
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
ORDER BY 
CASE WHEN ProductCode LIKE @SearchTerm + '%' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
,CASE WHEN ProductCode LIKE @SearchTerm + '%' THEN ProductCode ELSE NULL END ASC
, ProductCode ASC
```

Comment: sorry this just doesn't work (even if I comment out `, Citicode ASC`

Comment: Fixed, the first order by condition eliminates the null value issue that was stopping the order by

Answer (score 0):

As an option, UNION solution can be applied here:

```
SELECT ProductCode
FROM Product
WHERE ProductCode LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'
union
SELECT ProductCode
FROM Product
WHERE ProductCode LIKE '%' + @SearchTerm + '%'
and ProductCode NOT LIKE @SearchTerm + '%'
```

after that we can wrap this query and group by with outer query

Comment: Union only allows one order by condition for the entire statement (i.e both the first and second select) so you will still have to perform a cased order by. Relying on the default order that sql server will read the data is unwise. If you are relying on an order or requiring one then you should be putting that in the sql.

Comment: you're right, i've forgot about this nuance. upvoting your solution.